# What's the difference in these "wish" sentences and which ones are correct?

Tags: meaning

1. What's the difference in these "wish" sentences and which ones are correct?

I wish that day hadn't come

I wish that day would never come

I wish that day didnt come

I wish that day wouldnt have come

I wish that day wouldnt come

2. Do these sentences have exactly the same meaning?

I wish that day hadn't come

I wish that day had never come

Comment: 'I wish ...' relating to past events known to have / not to have happened means 'I['m sure] I'd be far happier were the opposite true.' _I wish I had won the knobbly knees contest at Bognor Regis. / I wish Covid had never arisen._ Used about future possibilities, it's unusual outside fixed expressions (I wish you well / a merry Christmas / all the best / many more happy years) and means (outside the magic charm sense) _I hope you have ..._ And _I wish that day never comes_ would almost always be _I hope that day never comes_.

Comment: Would you please add apostrophes to your contracted forms. Thank you.

Comment: Please finish reading the [Tour] to learn why this question is inappropriate here. You might try SE English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1):

"I wish that day hadn't come" - Used when the day did come.

"I wish that day would never come" - Used when the day has not yet come.

"I wish that day didnt come" - Not used, although the construction "I wish that birds didn't poop on my car" would be OK.

"I wish that day wouldnt have come" - Not used. The sentiment was expressed in the first example.

"I wish that day wouldnt come" - Not used, but like the third example, "I wish the birds wouldn't poop on my car" is OK.

In the case of #2,

"I wish that day had never come" is more emphatic than "I wish that day hadn't come", but they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

2:

"I wish that day hadn't come" would be used when the "that day" has actually happened and I am experiencing "that day" now, and I wish it hadn't occurred. The usage would be more in the present narrative.

"I wish that day had never come" would mean "that day" happened some time in the past (perhaps more than once), and I now wish it had never occurred, even once.

1:
The sentence "I wish that day didn't come" does not seem good construct.